# How to include crc32 function in a query?

Tags: php, database

I need to query data coming from 3 fields of the same table and to apply crc32 function to the result. So in practice is necessary to fetch and join the 3 value such "myfield1myfield2myfield3" and apply crc32 function to joined data for finally get the result...all in a single query.

Here crc32 reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_crc32.asp

I precise I'm not a coder so I have very small knowledge in Database management and PHP.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_crc32 `SELECT CRC32(CONCAT(field1, field2, field3));`. Referencing w3schools for a php function is painful. http://php.net/crc32

Comment: A far better reference for the PHP crc32() function than w3schools: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php

Comment: so in my case the full syntax will be this?: SELECT CRC32(CONCAT(field1, field2, field3)) FROM `mytable` WHERE `user_id` = [user_id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after testing the final answer with correct syntax for my specific case was this:

```
    SELECT CRC32( CONCAT( `id`, `email`, `username` ) ) FROM `#__users` WHERE `id` = '[user_id]'
```

Many thank to Mike.B who helped me and happy new year to everybody.